# Jquery add attribute and get the value (laravel)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a following html code.

```js
$(".category-tab").on('click', function() {
  var category_id = $(this).data("id");
  $("#search-form").removeAttr("data-categoryid");
  $("#search-form").attr("data-categoryid", category_id);
});

$("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var category_id = $(this).data('categoryid');


  var country_id = $('#country').val();
  var state_id = $('#state').val();
  var search_text = $('#search-text').val();
  console.log(category_id);
  console.log(country_id);
  console.log(state_id);
  console.log(search_text);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link category-tab  active " data-id="1" data-toggle="tab" href="#montesorri" role="tab">Montessori</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link category-tab " data-id="2" data-toggle="tab" href="#school" role="tab">School</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link category-tab " data-id="3" data-toggle="tab" href="#college" role="tab">College</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link category-tab " data-id="4" data-toggle="tab" href="#institute" role="tab">Institute</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link category-tab " data-id="5" data-toggle="tab" href="#hostel" role="tab">Hostel</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link category-tab " data-id="6" data-toggle="tab" href="#University" role="tab">University</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class=" page-description" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
  <form id="search-form" data-categoryid="4">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <select name="country_id" id="country" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%;" required="">
<option value="" selected="" disabled="">-- Select Country --</option>
 <option value="1" data-id="1">Afghanistan</option>
 <option value="2" data-id="2">Albania</option>
 <option value="3" data-id="3">Algeria</option>
 <option value="4" data-id="4">American Samoa</option>
 <option value="5" data-id="5">Andorra</option>
 <option value="6" data-id="6">Angola</option>
 <option value="7" data-id="7">Anguilla</option>
 <option value="8" data-id="8">Antarctica</option>
 <option value="9" data-id="9">Antigua And Barbuda</option>
 <option value="10" data-id="10">Argentina</option>
 <option value="11" data-id="11">Armenia</option>
 <option value="12" data-id="12">Aruba</option>
 <option value="13" data-id="13">Australia</option>
 <option value="14" data-id="14">Austria</option>
 <option value="15" data-id="15">Azerbaijan</option>
 <option value="16" data-id="16">Bahamas The</option>
 <option value="17" data-id="17">Bahrain</option>
 <option value="18" data-id="18">Bangladesh</option>
 <option value="19" data-id="19">Barbados</option>
 <option value="20" data-id="20">Belarus</option>
 <option value="21" data-id="21">Belgium</option>
 <option value="22" data-id="22">Belize</option>
 <option value="23" data-id="23">Benin</option>
 <option value="24" data-id="24">Bermuda</option>
 <option value="25" data-id="25">Bhutan</option>
 <option value="26" data-id="26">Bolivia</option>
 <option value="27" data-id="27">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
 <option value="28" data-id="28">Botswana</option>
 <option value="29" data-id="29">Bouvet Island</option>
 <option value="30" data-id="30">Brazil</option>
 <option value="31" data-id="31">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
 <option value="32" data-id="32">Brunei</option>
 <option value="33" data-id="33">Bulgaria</option>
 <option value="34" data-id="34">Burkina Faso</option>
 <option value="35" data-id="35">Burundi</option>
 <option value="36" data-id="36">Cambodia</option>
 <option value="37" data-id="37">Cameroon</option>
 <option value="38" data-id="38">Canada</option>
 <option value="39" data-id="39">Cape Verde</option>
 <option value="40" data-id="40">Cayman Islands</option>
 <option value="41" data-id="41">Central African Republic</option>
 <option value="42" data-id="42">Chad</option>
 <option value="43" data-id="43">Chile</option>
 <option value="44" data-id="44">China</option>
 <option value="45" data-id="45">Christmas Island</option>
 <option value="46" data-id="46">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
 <option value="47" data-id="47">Colombia</option>
 <option value="48" data-id="48">Comoros</option>
 <option value="49" data-id="49">Congo</option>
 <option value="50" data-id="50">Congo The Democratic Republic Of The</option>
 <option value="51" data-id="51">Cook Islands</option>
 <option value="52" data-id="52">Costa Rica</option>
 <option value="53" data-id="53">Cote D Ivoire (Ivory Coast)</option>
 <option value="54" data-id="54">Croatia (Hrvatska)</option>
 <option value="55" data-id="55">Cuba</option>
 <option value="56" data-id="56">Cyprus</option>
 <option value="57" data-id="57">Czech Republic</option>
 <option value="58" data-id="58">Denmark</option>
 <option value="59" data-id="59">Djibouti</option>
 <option value="60" data-id="60">Dominica</option>
 <option value="61" data-id="61">Dominican Republic</option>
 <option value="62" data-id="62">East Timor</option>
 <option value="63" data-id="63">Ecuador</option>
 <option value="64" data-id="64">Egypt</option>
 <option value="65" data-id="65">El Salvador</option>
 <option value="66" data-id="66">Equatorial Guinea</option>
 <option value="67" data-id="67">Eritrea</option>
 <option value="68" data-id="68">Estonia</option>
 <option value="69" data-id="69">Ethiopia</option>
 <option value="70" data-id="70">External Territories of Australia</option>
 <option value="71" data-id="71">Falkland Islands</option>
 <option value="72" data-id="72">Faroe Islands</option>
 <option value="73" data-id="73">Fiji Islands</option>
 <option value="74" data-id="74">Finland</option>
 <option value="75" data-id="75">France</option>
 <option value="76" data-id="76">French Guiana</option>
 <option value="77" data-id="77">French Polynesia</option>
 <option value="78" data-id="78">French Southern Territories</option>
 <option value="79" data-id="79">Gabon</option>
 <option value="80" data-id="80">Gambia The</option>
 <option value="81" data-id="81">Georgia</option>
 <option value="82" data-id="82">Germany</option>
 <option value="83" data-id="83">Ghana</option>
 <option value="84" data-id="84">Gibraltar</option>
 <option value="85" data-id="85">Greece</option>
 <option value="86" data-id="86">Greenland</option>
 <option value="87" data-id="87">Grenada</option>
 <option value="88" data-id="88">Guadeloupe</option>
 <option value="89" data-id="89">Guam</option>
 <option value="90" data-id="90">Guatemala</option>
 <option value="91" data-id="91">Guernsey and Alderney</option>
 <option value="92" data-id="92">Guinea</option>
 <option value="93" data-id="93">Guinea-Bissau</option>
 <option value="94" data-id="94">Guyana</option>
 <option value="95" data-id="95">Haiti</option>
 <option value="96" data-id="96">Heard and McDonald Islands</option>
 <option value="97" data-id="97">Honduras</option>
 <option value="98" data-id="98">Hong Kong S.A.R.</option>
 <option value="99" data-id="99">Hungary</option>
 <option value="100" data-id="100">Iceland</option>
 <option value="101" data-id="101">India</option>
 <option value="102" data-id="102">Indonesia</option>
 <option value="103" data-id="103">Iran</option>
 <option value="104" data-id="104">Iraq</option>
 <option value="105" data-id="105">Ireland</option>
 <option value="106" data-id="106">Israel</option>
 <option value="107" data-id="107">Italy</option>
 <option value="108" data-id="108">Jamaica</option>
 <option value="109" data-id="109">Japan</option>
 <option value="110" data-id="110">Jersey</option>
 <option value="111" data-id="111">Jordan</option>
 <option value="112" data-id="112">Kazakhstan</option>
 <option value="113" data-id="113">Kenya</option>
 <option value="114" data-id="114">Kiribati</option>
 <option value="115" data-id="115">Korea North</option>
 <option value="116" data-id="116">Korea South</option>
 <option value="117" data-id="117">Kuwait</option>
 <option value="118" data-id="118">Kyrgyzstan</option>
 <option value="119" data-id="119">Laos</option>
 <option value="120" data-id="120">Latvia</option>
 <option value="121" data-id="121">Lebanon</option>
 <option value="122" data-id="122">Lesotho</option>
 <option value="123" data-id="123">Liberia</option>
 <option value="124" data-id="124">Libya</option>
 <option value="125" data-id="125">Liechtenstein</option>
 <option value="126" data-id="126">Lithuania</option>
 <option value="127" data-id="127">Luxembourg</option>
 <option value="128" data-id="128">Macau S.A.R.</option>
 <option value="129" data-id="129">Macedonia</option>
 <option value="130" data-id="130">Madagascar</option>
 <option value="131" data-id="131">Malawi</option>
 <option value="132" data-id="132">Malaysia</option>
 <option value="133" data-id="133">Maldives</option>
 <option value="134" data-id="134">Mali</option>
 <option value="135" data-id="135">Malta</option>
 <option value="136" data-id="136">Man (Isle of)</option>
 <option value="137" data-id="137">Marshall Islands</option>
 <option value="138" data-id="138">Martinique</option>
 <option value="139" data-id="139">Mauritania</option>
 <option value="140" data-id="140">Mauritius</option>
 <option value="141" data-id="141">Mayotte</option>
 <option value="142" data-id="142">Mexico</option>
 <option value="143" data-id="143">Micronesia</option>
 <option value="144" data-id="144">Moldova</option>
 <option value="145" data-id="145">Monaco</option>
 <option value="146" data-id="146">Mongolia</option>
 <option value="147" data-id="147">Montserrat</option>
 <option value="148" data-id="148">Morocco</option>
 <option value="149" data-id="149">Mozambique</option>
 <option value="150" data-id="150">Myanmar</option>
 <option value="151" data-id="151">Namibia</option>
 <option value="152" data-id="152">Nauru</option>
 <option value="153" data-id="153">Nepal</option>
 <option value="154" data-id="154">Netherlands Antilles</option>
 <option value="155" data-id="155">Netherlands The</option>
 <option value="156" data-id="156">New Caledonia</option>
 <option value="157" data-id="157">New Zealand</option>
 <option value="158" data-id="158">Nicaragua</option>
 <option value="159" data-id="159">Niger</option>
 <option value="160" data-id="160">Nigeria</option>
 <option value="161" data-id="161">Niue</option>
 <option value="162" data-id="162">Norfolk Island</option>
 <option value="163" data-id="163">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
 <option value="164" data-id="164">Norway</option>
 <option value="165" data-id="165">Oman</option>
 <option value="166" data-id="166">Pakistan</option>
 <option value="167" data-id="167">Palau</option>
 <option value="168" data-id="168">Palestinian Territory Occupied</option>
 <option value="169" data-id="169">Panama</option>
 <option value="170" data-id="170">Papua new Guinea</option>
 <option value="171" data-id="171">Paraguay</option>
 <option value="172" data-id="172">Peru</option>
 <option value="173" data-id="173">Philippines</option>
 <option value="174" data-id="174">Pitcairn Island</option>
 <option value="175" data-id="175">Poland</option>
 <option value="176" data-id="176">Portugal</option>
 <option value="177" data-id="177">Puerto Rico</option>
 <option value="178" data-id="178">Qatar</option>
 <option value="179" data-id="179">Reunion</option>
 <option value="180" data-id="180">Romania</option>
 <option value="181" data-id="181">Russia</option>
 <option value="182" data-id="182">Rwanda</option>
 <option value="183" data-id="183">Saint Helena</option>
 <option value="184" data-id="184">Saint Kitts And Nevis</option>
 <option value="185" data-id="185">Saint Lucia</option>
 <option value="186" data-id="186">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
 <option value="187" data-id="187">Saint Vincent And The Grenadines</option>
 <option value="188" data-id="188">Samoa</option>
 <option value="189" data-id="189">San Marino</option>
 <option value="190" data-id="190">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
 <option value="191" data-id="191">Saudi Arabia</option>
 <option value="192" data-id="192">Senegal</option>
 <option value="193" data-id="193">Serbia</option>
 <option value="194" data-id="194">Seychelles</option>
 <option value="195" data-id="195">Sierra Leone</option>
 <option value="196" data-id="196">Singapore</option>
 <option value="197" data-id="197">Slovakia</option>
 <option value="198" data-id="198">Slovenia</option>
 <option value="199" data-id="199">Smaller Territories of the UK</option>
 <option value="200" data-id="200">Solomon Islands</option>
 <option value="201" data-id="201">Somalia</option>
 <option value="202" data-id="202">South Africa</option>
 <option value="203" data-id="203">South Georgia</option>
 <option value="204" data-id="204">South Sudan</option>
 <option value="205" data-id="205">Spain</option>
 <option value="206" data-id="206">Sri Lanka</option>
 <option value="207" data-id="207">Sudan</option>
 <option value="208" data-id="208">Suriname</option>
 <option value="209" data-id="209">Svalbard And Jan Mayen Islands</option>
 <option value="210" data-id="210">Swaziland</option>
 <option value="211" data-id="211">Sweden</option>
 <option value="212" data-id="212">Switzerland</option>
 <option value="213" data-id="213">Syria</option>
 <option value="214" data-id="214">Taiwan</option>
 <option value="215" data-id="215">Tajikistan</option>
 <option value="216" data-id="216">Tanzania</option>
 <option value="217" data-id="217">Thailand</option>
 <option value="218" data-id="218">Togo</option>
 <option value="219" data-id="219">Tokelau</option>
 <option value="220" data-id="220">Tonga</option>
 <option value="221" data-id="221">Trinidad And Tobago</option>
 <option value="222" data-id="222">Tunisia</option>
 <option value="223" data-id="223">Turkey</option>
 <option value="224" data-id="224">Turkmenistan</option>
 <option value="225" data-id="225">Turks And Caicos Islands</option>
 <option value="226" data-id="226">Tuvalu</option>
 <option value="227" data-id="227">Uganda</option>
 <option value="228" data-id="228">Ukraine</option>
 <option value="229" data-id="229">United Arab Emirates</option>
 <option value="230" data-id="230">United Kingdom</option>
 <option value="231" data-id="231">United States</option>
 <option value="232" data-id="232">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
 <option value="233" data-id="233">Uruguay</option>
 <option value="234" data-id="234">Uzbekistan</option>
 <option value="235" data-id="235">Vanuatu</option>
 <option value="236" data-id="236">Vatican City State (Holy See)</option>
 <option value="237" data-id="237">Venezuela</option>
 <option value="238" data-id="238">Vietnam</option>
 <option value="239" data-id="239">Virgin Islands (British)</option>
 <option value="240" data-id="240">Virgin Islands (US)</option>
 <option value="241" data-id="241">Wallis And Futuna Islands</option>
 <option value="242" data-id="242">Western Sahara</option>
 <option value="243" data-id="243">Yemen</option>
 <option value="244" data-id="244">Yugoslavia</option>
 <option value="245" data-id="245">Zambia</option>
 <option value="246" data-id="246">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mar0-select">
        <select name="state_id" id="state" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%;" required="">
                      <option value="" selected="" disabled="">-- No States --</option>
                  </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="search-text" class="form-control" placeholder="search Monetessori">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

What I wanna do is When I Click on any tab, I wanna get the id of data-id.And add the `data-categoryid` attribute to the #search-form div. When I click any tab I get the id and the `data-categoryid` attribute is added to `#search-form` with id. Now What the problem was when i `console.log($(this).data('categoryid'))` im getting always the same value. When i Inspect into my browser i found that the #search-form div has got data-categoryid value is changing and not showing when i `console.log($(this).data('categoryid'))` as in the script.

Comment: why not remove this `$("#search-form").removeAttr("data-categoryid");`
and `$("#search-form").attr("data-categoryid", category_id);` .... And use this  `$("#search-form").data( 'categoryid',category_id );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of changing/updating `data()` is

`$("#search-form").data( 'categoryid',category_id );`

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/data/

The `.data()` method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

Comment: Great to hear, Please accept my answer if this helped you :)